# Testing in Meteor

Tags: reactjs, testing, meteor

I am trying to add tests in Meteor. I added my tests in the folder 'imports'. This is the test file:

```js
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { chai } from 'meteor/practicalmeteor:chai';

if (Meteor.isClient) {
  describe('Client Tasks', () => {
    describe('methods', () => {
      it('can delete owned task', () => {
        Meteor.call('getVideoData', function (error, res) {
          if (error) console.log('error', error)
          console.log('ok', res);
        })
      });
    });
  });
}
```

I tried to call a method and log the result but I get the following error:

> There is no route for the path: /

The result from the console log is:

> error {"isClientSafe":true,"error":404,"reason":"Method 'getVideoData' not found","message":"Method 'getVideoData' not found [404]","errorType":"Meteor.Error"}

and

> ok undefined

I used Meteor for the back end and React for the front end.

Am I missing something in the test file or is it related to something else?

This is the link to the repo [github](https://github.com/pierroberto/PadTube)

Answer (score 0):

The immediate problem you are seeing is `"Method 'getVideoData' not found"`.  That is because running `meteor test` will only load the modules you have specifically `import`ed.  [It does not eagerly load your project](https://guide.meteor.com/testing.html#test-modes) as we are used to when serving meteor in local development mode.  You've only imported `Meteor` and `chai` into this test so the test knows nothing about any methods you've written in other files in your project.

However, that leads to a more fundamental problem in that `meteor test` does not run a front end and back end anyways, so methods are not testable as a way to retrieve data from the server when testing the front end.  Instead, when testing the front end you need to stub/mock the call to `Meteor.call('getVideoData')` and all you can really do is assert that it's been called and supply your own fake return data, as shown [in this example](https://guide.meteor.com/testing.html#simple-react-unit-test).

Then you would need to write separate backend tests to verify the method (and hopefully the compartmentalized functions it calls) are properly retrieving the correct data.